# mobile vision api doesnt detect barcodes

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I tried the mobile vision api for reading barcodes. But it gives the result only for the official sample QR code which they have. How can I read 1D barcodes?
My code :

```
if(checkIsOperational()) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                R.drawable.barcode);
        Log.d("BarcodeActivity","bitmap: "+myBitmap);
        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
        SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = mDetector.detect(frame);
        Log.d("BarcodeActivity","barcodes.size: "+barcodes.size());
        if(barcodes.size()>0) {
            Barcode thisCode = barcodes.valueAt(0);
            resultText.setText(thisCode.rawValue);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Not detected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



private boolean checkIsOperational() {
    if(!mDetector.isOperational()){
        resultText.setText("Could not set up the detector!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: try tesseract ocr or google vision cloud projects...https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Comment: does cloud vision have barcode detection? I see only text detections

Comment: what type is your 1D barcode? Google Mobile Vision support this formats EAN-13, EAN-8, UPC-A, UPC-E, Code-39, Code-93, Code-128, ITF, Codabar

Comment: @SahanaPrabhakar yes google vision has barcode detection https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview

Comment: @appersiano - yes tried with the supported formats itself

Comment: @SnehalGongle -  it is the same thing I am using currently. The mobile vision api.